# Angular Speed up the home page

Tags: javascript, angular

I am a web developer of a company using angular. My recent task is to speed up the home page of our company. Google insights tool says that our home page loading speed is too low. I tried to apply angular universal on our website already, and now the score for our website is only 36 for mobile and 76 for desktop.
After angular universal, the size of home page itself is only 500k, but the Google insights tool will still wait for loading the entire application before score the page.
Is there any way for me to make the website even quicker except angular universal or lazy loading (after lazy loading still 1.5MB for main.js)?

Angular version is 8. AOT and prod are already used.
Thanks for you all!

Comment: What version of Angular are you on? What browsers are you targeting? Are you deploying an AOT build of your project? Happy to help, just need more details :) One thing you can do is run `ng build --prod --statsJson and it'll give you a file you can analyze with something like "webpack-bundle-analyzer". Maybe that will point up some new optimization targets.

Comment: I am using angular 8 now. AOT and prod flag are already deployed. I have already tried webpack-bundle-analyze and it shows that only core parts of angular are loaded. Actually, after angular universal the size of the home page is only 500kb around. My problem is the google speed test will wait for the whole js files being loading, rather than score only with the rendered page. Anyway thank you so much for replying!